# Styling bootstrap input-group-addon on input focus

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Even if I don't really have hope, I want to style bootstrap `input-group-addon` *in css only* when the related input is focused. If the input is before the addon, like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Enter email">
<div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
```

No problem, a simple :

```
input:focus + .input-group-addon {
  background: $color;
  color: white;
}
```

But assumed it can be placed after as well, if someone has a css based solution in this case, it would be wonderful.

Comment: What's the question? Your CSS works, but you're not creating the `input-group-addon` correctly.  Also don't include PHP in your CSS. Fixed here: http://www.bootply.com/i3Rk0HZbGo

Comment: The input group was implicite. You're talking about the div instead of span ? My bad then. The question is simple, I want to style it if it's placed before the input as well.

Comment: Ok good point...odd that it only works if the addon is to the right.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that using pure CSS but using JQuery you can add these few simple lines to your code:

```
$( ".form-control" ).focus(function() {
    $(this).prev('.input-group-addon').removeClass().addClass('input-group-addon-focus');
    $(this).next('.input-group-addon').removeClass().addClass('input-group-addon-focus');
});

$( ".form-control" ).focusout(function() {
    $(this).prev('.input-group-addon-focus').removeClass().addClass('input-group-addon');
    $(this).next('.input-group-addon-focus').removeClass().addClass('input-group-addon');
});
```

If your "addon" not placed before or after Control EXACTLY, you can wrap control and addon in a wrapper and modify code using

```
.parent('.wrapperClass').children('.input-group-addon')
```

The complete code: **[JSFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/cGR8M/1/)**

Comment: Why is it that he can't do it with pure CSS? Also, if you're going to use jQuery you might as well create solution that works for placement either before or after.

Comment: Yeah, i'm well aware of this solution. But it's a big project, I don't want javascript in every direction over such littles things. But thank anyway, i don't think there is a solution.

Comment: You can't find other solution, CSS3 don't have previous selector, If you want to do this, you have to use javascript.
If you worry about performance or something, it's not a big deal, because bootstrap use much more javascript to doing more little things!

Comment: I don't. I know it's a drop of water for performances. But my work will be used by others people. I want to make it easy to use, not full of javascript for styling. But thank, i will re-think the style.

Comment: @Dan: At first i ONLY answer the question that asked about "Before" case, but now update code for all situations for other people with probably same question.

Comment: @Moshtaf siblings('selector') is faster than parent().children(), if you want to edit your answer

Comment: Finally someone understands what i've been trying to do in CSS! Thank You!